# How can I remove the result that I get random in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to show random texts but I need these not to be repeated. Here is the code, Thank you.

```js
var textos = new Array()
textos[0] = " text1";
textos[1] = " tex2.";
textos[2] = " tex3.";
textos[3] = " tex4";
textos[4] = "  text5";

function aleatorio() {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
  nro = Math.floor(Math.random() * (textos.length - 0) + 0);
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = textos[nro];
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
<button onclick="aleatorio()">Siguente</button>
```

When I print the texts they are repeated and break the objective of the page I want to make.

Answer (score 0):

**One way can be:**

Delete the position that is used so that next time it's not repeated.
Example:

```js
var textos = new Array()
textos[0] = " text1 ";
textos[1] = " text2 ";
textos[2] = " text3 ";
textos[3] = " text4 ";
textos[4] = " text5 ";

function aleatorio() {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
  if (textos.length > 0) {
    nro = Math.floor(Math.random() * (textos.length - 0) + 0);
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = textos[nro];
    //delete this index from the array so that it does not repeat
    textos.splice(nro, 1);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "All Done";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
<button onclick="aleatorio()">Siguente</button>
```

**Another way can be:**

Store the indices that are already used and if the random generator picks from those indices that you recalculate the new random number:

```js
var textos = new Array()
textos[0] = " text1 ";
textos[1] = " text2 ";
textos[2] = " text3 ";
textos[3] = " text4 ";
textos[4] = " text5 ";

var done = new Array();

function aleatorio() {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
  if (done.length < textos.length) {
    var newVal = false;
    do {
      nro = Math.floor(Math.random() * (textos.length - 0) + 0);
      if (done.indexOf(nro) == -1) {
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = textos[nro];
        //add this random index to the array so that it can be matched next time
        done.push(nro);
        newVal = true;
      }
    } while (!newVal);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "All Done";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
<button onclick="aleatorio()">Siguente</button>
```